# Django not serving images based on ImageFiled

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having issues serving images based on the ImageField in Django.

`models.py` part looks like that:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='main_image')
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name='images')

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/', blank=True)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taken = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

`settings.py` contains the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Also included what I've found in other SO topics in the `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static, staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from markdownx import urls as markdownx

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
] + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the end I put it in the html template like that:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block leftcolumn %}
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card" style="max-width: 100%">
        <h2><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <h5>published: {{ post.published_date }}, by: {{ post.author }}</h5>
        <div><img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}"></div>
        <p>{{ post.byline }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the image is not shown..
I can see the image if I go to the url `host:8000/media/pictures/test_photo.jpg`and in general I can display images on the page (e.g. within django-markdownx field) but not through ImageField url.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: if the answer was correct and it was indeed the problem. Please mark it as correct. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
<div><img src="{{ post.main_image.url }}"></div>
```

should be:

```
<div><img src="{{ post.main_image.picture.url }}"></div>
```

The reason is your model `Image` does not have an `url` method. The method belongs to the `ImageField`, in this case `picture`.

Comment: That fixed it. It wasn't very clear in the documentation, thanks dethos!